# Cloud Speech API return code=UNAUTHENTICATED, cause =java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account:

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-speech, boringssl, grpc-java

I use Google Cloud Speech API(StreamingRecognize via gRPC) for speech recognizing in my app. I got the problem with authenticate on Android devices API level < 23.

```
V/NativeCrypto: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x5b0ed2d0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
                                                                 error:10000095:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:ERROR_PARSING_EXTENSION (third_party/openssl/boringssl/src/ssl/t1_lib.c:2336 0x5b0fcd50:0x00000001)
                                                                 error:100000be:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:PARSE_TLSEXT (third_party/openssl/boringssl/src/ssl/handshake_client.c:893 0x5aca7d31:0x00000000)

V/NativeCrypto: SSL shutdown failed: ssl=0x5b0ed2d0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
                                                                 error:100000fa:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SHUTDOWN_WHILE_IN_INIT (third_party/openssl/boringssl/src/ssl/ssl_lib.c:703 0x5aca7d31:0x00000000)

V/NativeCrypto: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x58523fb8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
                                                                 error:1000042e:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION (third_party/openssl/boringssl/src/ssl/tls_record.c:469 0x5b258bd8:0x00000001)

V/NativeCrypto: SSL shutdown failed: ssl=0x58523fb8: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
                                                                 error:100000fa:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SHUTDOWN_WHILE_IN_INIT (third_party/openssl/boringssl/src/ssl/ssl_lib.c:703 0x5aca7d31:0x00000000)

Status{code=UNAUTHENTICATED, description=null, cause=java.io.IOException: Error getting access token for service account: }
```

I don't get this error everytime, but only on specific case. I have two activity. Let's name A and B.

Activity A has a button, which starts Activity B.
Activity B communicates with Google Cloud Speech API and show results in TextView.

I get this error after following steps(on Samsung GT-P5110 (Android 4.2.2)):

1. Start Activity A -> press Button to start Activity B.

// In first time everything is Okay. I receive result from server and show this.

2. Close Activity B (press Back Button or call onBackPressed or finish).
3. Press button to start Activity B.

// In this moment I get error, which was show above.

I get this error on Lenovo A1000 (API 5.0.1) and Xiaomi Mi4c (5.0.1) after:

1. Start Activity A -> press Button to start Activity B.
2. Close Activity B (press Back Button or call onBackPressed or finish).
3. Press button to start Activity B.

// Everything is Okay

4. Close Activity B (press Back Button or call onBackPressed or finish).
5. Minimize app .
6. After 5-6 or more minutes go back to Activity A.
7. Start Activity B.

// In this moment I always get this error.

After restart application everything is Okay, but error appears after reopen Activity B.

Who knows how I can solve this problem?

I use Play Services Dynamic Security Provider ([It is required for gRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#tls-on-android)).
I installed last version Google Play Services (9.6.83). It doesn't resolve the problem.

I create ManagedChannel by following code:

```
GoogleCredentials creds = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentials);
    creds = creds.createScoped(OAUTH2_SCOPES);
    OkHttpChannelProvider provider = new OkHttpChannelProvider();
    OkHttpChannelBuilder builder = provider.builderForAddress(host, port);
ManagedChannel channel = builder.intercept(new ClientAuthInterceptor(creds, Executors
            .newSingleThreadExecutor
                    ()))
            .build();

private static final List<String> OAUTH2_SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform");
```

Create SpeechGrpc.SpeechStub :

```
SpeechGrpc.SpeechStub mSpeechClient = SpeechGrpc.newStub(channel);
```

build.gradle (Module: app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.protobuf'

protobuf {
protoc {
    artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
}
plugins {
    javalite {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0"
    }
    grpc {
        artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.0.1'
    }
}
generateProtoTasks {
    all().each { task ->
        task.plugins {
            javalite {}
            grpc {
                // Options added to --grpc_out
                option 'lite'
            }
        }
    }

}
}
android {
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "someAppID"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.10"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

def grpcVersion = '1.0.1'

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
  compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.0'
  compile "io.grpc:grpc-okhttp:${grpcVersion}"
  compile "io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:${grpcVersion}"
  compile "io.grpc:grpc-stub:${grpcVersion}"
  compile "io.grpc:grpc-auth:${grpcVersion}"
  compile ('com.google.auth:google-auth-library-oauth2-http:0.3.0'){
      exclude module: 'httpclient'
  }
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
  compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.1'
}
```

build.gradle (Project)

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
    classpath 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-gradle-plugin:0.8.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}
allprojects {
repositories {
//        mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this issue [in the forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-speech-discuss/OFJ-oqY8Zeg).

The problem occurs because you are embedding your Service Account credentials in the application. After a period of time, when the token that is created is internally refreshed, the error is thrown from:

`com.google.auth.oauth2.ServiceAccountCredentials.refreshAccessToken` [link](https://github.com/google/google-auth-library-java/blob/master/oauth2_http/java/com/google/auth/oauth2/ServiceAccountCredentials.java#L259)

In production, you will supply the access token from your server and therefore be able to instantiate the `GoogleCredentials` as so:

```
    final GoogleCredentials googleCredentials = new GoogleCredentials(accessToken) {
        @Override
        public AccessToken refreshAccessToken() throws IOException {
            return accessToken;
        }
    }.createScoped(OAUTH2_SCOPES);
```

This will prevent the error from being thrown.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Is it dangerous embedding Service Account credentials in the final application(final apk)? If yes, how I can safely save credentials.json in my project? I can not get access token from server because server does't exist?

Comment: @Paukdcn You shouldn't store any keys in your application, as it can be reversed engineered. If someone uses your credentials, it could cost you a lot of money. Firebase is perfect for tasks like this. You would control distributing temporary access tokens from there. It's not as daunting as it sounds, Google have made things like this easy to integrate into Android. You'll have it up and running in a few hours.